# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

i have the following code parts:

```
typedef struct Object* ObjectP;

ObjectP CreateObject(void *key) {

    printf("GOT %d\n",(*(int*) key));
    ObjectP objP = (ObjectP) malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if (objP == NULL) {
        //TODO ReportError(MEM_OUT);
        return NULL;
    }
    objP->_key = key;
    objP->_next = NULL;
    objP->_numInChain = 1;

    return objP;
```

}

```
typedef struct Object {
  ObjectP _next;
  void* _key;
  int _numInChain;
} Object;
```

and in another file:

```
void IntPrint(const void *key) {
    assert(key != NULL);
    printf("%d",*((const int*)key));
}
```

and in another file I have the main() :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 int* key = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
 *key = 20;
 ObjectP a = CreateObject(key);
 IntPrint(a->_key);  //THIS DOESN'T COMPILE
 return 0;
}
```

IntPrint doesn't compile. it writes:
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
and i can't understand why, because IntPrint recieves void* and a->_key is also void*.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you post the code pieces in the order they get compiled?

Answer (score 3):

You posted a bunch of virtually irrelevant pieces of code, but omitted the most important one: what is `ObjectP` and how it is defined? The compiler tells you that it is defined as a pointer to incomplete type. That's your problem. What exactly is wrong with the definition is impossible to say without actually seeing it.

**After the edit:** Your problem is that the definition of `struct Object` is not visible at the point where you are trying to access `a->key` (in.e. in `main`). You either forgot to include it or something like that. Is the definition of `struct Object` located in the same header file as definition of `ObjectP`?

Answer (score 2):

Where do you have ObjectP defined? I suggest not declaring it before Object is fully defined:

```
typedef struct Object {
  struct Object*  _next;
  void* _key;
  int _numInChain;
} Object;

typedef Object* ObjectP;
```

This way it should be always safe to use ObjectP. However, without you posting more code, this is just a blind guess.

Comment: i don't think it's the problem. typedef ObjectP is defined in 
GenericHashMap.h (in the header), and the struct Object is defined in 
GenericHashMap.c.. i'm including the header at the beginning.

Comment: @Asher: Well, that's your problem. You defined `struct Object` in a .c file, so it is not visible to your `main` function. So you get an incomplete type error, as you should. (I assume `main` function is in a different .c file).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your `main` function:

```
IntPrint((const void *) a->_key);
```

The definition of `_key` in the structure `Object` doesn't have the modifier `constant` and that could cause a warning or an error depending the flags you're using when compiling.