# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type when compil C program

Tags: c

I put here a brief source code because the source is too long. you can find the full source code is at this git repository: https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe

In fact I use strophe as a library in my main C program which is an openWrt package.

source code of common.h (libstrophe)

```
/** run-time context **/

typedef enum {
    XMPP_LOOP_NOTSTARTED,
    XMPP_LOOP_RUNNING,
    XMPP_LOOP_QUIT
} xmpp_loop_status_t;

typedef struct _xmpp_connlist_t {
    xmpp_conn_t *conn;
    struct _xmpp_connlist_t *next;
} xmpp_connlist_t;

struct _xmpp_ctx_t {
    const xmpp_mem_t *mem;
    const xmpp_log_t *log;

    xmpp_loop_status_t loop_status;
    xmpp_connlist_t *connlist;
};
```

this is the header file strophe.h source code (libstrophe) :

```
/
    * user-replaceable memory allocator */
    typedef struct _xmpp_mem_t xmpp_mem_t;

    /* user-replaceable log object */
    typedef struct _xmpp_log_t xmpp_log_t;

    /* opaque run time context containing the above hooks */
    typedef struct _xmpp_ctx_t xmpp_ctx_t;

    xmpp_ctx_t *xmpp_ctx_new(const xmpp_mem_t * const mem, 
                     const xmpp_log_t * const log);
    void xmpp_ctx_free(xmpp_ctx_t * const ctx);
    struct _xmpp_log_t {
        xmpp_log_handler handler;
        void *userdata;
        /* mutex_t lock; */
    };
```

ctx.c brief source code (libstrophe):

```
xmpp_ctx_t *xmpp_ctx_new(const xmpp_mem_t * const mem, 
             const xmpp_log_t * const log)
{
    xmpp_ctx_t *ctx = NULL;

    if (mem == NULL)
    ctx = xmpp_default_mem.alloc(sizeof(xmpp_ctx_t), NULL);
    else
    ctx = mem->alloc(sizeof(xmpp_ctx_t), mem->userdata);

    if (ctx != NULL) {
    if (mem != NULL) 
        ctx->mem = mem;
    else 
        ctx->mem = &xmpp_default_mem;

    if (log == NULL)
        ctx->log = &xmpp_default_log;
    else
        ctx->log = log;

    ctx->connlist = NULL;
    ctx->loop_status = 0;//XMPP_LOOP_NOTSTARTED;
    }

    return ctx;
}
```

the main C program

```
#include <strophe.h>

void main()
{
xmpp_ctx_t *ctx;
xmpp_conn_t *conn;
xmpp_log_t *log;
char *jid, *pass;


create a context */
log = xmpp_get_default_logger(XMPP_LEVEL_DEBUG); /* pass NULL instead to silence output */
ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, log);
/* create a connection */
conn = xmpp_conn_new(ctx);
/* setup authentication information */
xmpp_conn_set_jid(conn, "jid");
xmpp_conn_set_pass(conn, "pass");
/* initiate connection */
xmpp_connect_client(conn, "alt3.xmpp.l.google.com", 5222, conn_handler, ctx);
 ctx->loop_status = 1; // error error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/* enter the event loop -
our connect handler will trigger an exit */
xmpp_run(ctx);
/* release our connection and context */
xmpp_conn_release(conn);
xmpp_ctx_free(ctx);
/* final shutdown of the library */
xmpp_shutdown();
 }
```

when compiling using this source code I got this error :

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: Does main.c `#include` common.h, either directly or indirectly? I'm betting it does not.

Comment: @ Fred Larson : the common.h file contain #include "strophe.h"

Comment: Which line of code is the error message referencing?

Comment: in main C program : ctx->loop_status = 1; // error error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: And have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611539/error-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type?rq=1 or any of the other simiilar posts in the Related list?

Comment: I ask because I remember seeing a similar question recently (incomplete type with an enum in a struct)

Comment: The question in the first comment still stands (i.e., it hasn't been answered).

Comment: Btw, why assign to `1` if you have defined as an enum? Use the enum constants.

Comment: @Evert : is not that the problem ! I will do that after

Answer (score 1):

Is a circular dependency header problem.

file strophe.h has to be include before common.h

That because of types in strophe.h has to be known by common.h

```
#include "strophe.h"
#include "common.h"

void main()
{
    xmpp_ctx_t *ctx;

    xmpp_initialize();

    ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, log);
    /* create a connection */
    conn = xmpp_conn_new(ctx);
    xmpp_connect_client(conn, "alt3.xmpp.l.google.com", 5222, conn_handler,
            ctx);
    ctx->loop_status = 1; // error error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    xmpp_run(ctx);
}
```

Comment: I include only stophe.h. It is a library compiled for openwrt package

Comment: see stophe.h in git repo

Comment: The compiler is telling you that he doesn't know what are xmpp_mem_t and xmpp_log_t

Comment: the compiler doesn't know xmpp_loop_status_t struct

Comment: The compiler complains about a pointer to an incomplete type; at the line indicated by the comment, that would be `ctx`, which is of type `xmpp_ctx_t *`. The compiler doesn't know what `xmpp_ctx_t` is.

Comment: No. The compiler doesn't know how to reach loop_status because of it doesn't know the size of  xmpp_mem_t and xmpp_log_t

Comment: `loop_status` is a `xmpp_loop_status_t`, which is an `enum`; why does that need to know the size of `xmpp_mem_t` and `xmpp_log_t`?

Comment: Basically it has to know the structure of your struct. If it doesn't know what are those structures haw it can be work? Have you tried to add the 2 include I wrote you at the top of file where main function is wrote?